# Jquery mobile - How to add arrow left icon from rightto collapsible set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to add arrow left icon to collapsible item with existing add sing when collapsed  and subb sign when expanded from right to collapsible set in Jquery mobile ? Thank you.

[image: collapsible_set]

HTML:

```
<div id="set_featured" data-role="collapsible-set">
                        <div id="our_business" data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Our Business Activities</h3>                                                    
                        {section name=element loop=$sub_category_cat_210}
                        <a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$sub_category_cat_210[element].ID}_{$sub_category_cat_210[element].friendlyTitle}.html" target="_blank">
                            {$sub_category_cat_210[element].Title}
                        </a><br />
                        {/section}
                        </div>

                        <div id="portfolio" data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Portfolio</h3> 
                        {section name=element loop=$sub_category_cat_211}
                            <a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$sub_category_cat_211[element].ID}_{$sub_category_cat_211[element].friendlyTitle}.html">
                             {$sub_category_cat_211[element].Title}
                            </a><br />
                        {/section}                                                        
                        </div>
                        <div id="customer_references" data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Customer References</h3>
                        {section name=element loop=$sub_category_cat_10}
                            <a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$sub_category_cat_10[element].ID}_{$sub_category_cat_10[element].friendlyTitle}.html">
                             {$sub_category_cat_10[element].Title}  
                            </a><br />
                        {/section}
                        </div>                       
                        <div id="featured" data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Featured</h3>                                                                        
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Inspect</a>
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS CM4D</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Intelligence (OEE)</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Quality Products</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Academy</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Lean Six</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS MES</a><br />
                        </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Add these attributes to collapsible div `data-collapsed-icon="arrow-l"` and `data-expanded-icon="arrow-r"`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AmdUA/

Comment: Hi Omar, than you works. Is it possible to have add and subb signt from left and arrow-l from right together ? Thank you for answer

Comment: Are you using google translation? Porque entiendo nada.

Comment: Im sorry my english is bad, no Im not using google translation. Im trying to make sentence by myself. Is it possible to have two icons in each collapsible item ?

Comment: Everything is possible, it's a CSS job. You have to try.